# In Rails, How Can Get Time.zone.now.in_time_zone.end_of_day to show today's date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `rails 6.1.4` and `ruby 2.6.7`

In my controller's index action I am using this:

```
weights_controller.rb

def index
  # exercises entered today:
  @weights_today = Fitness::Weight.where(admin_user_id: session[:user_id])
                   .where(workout_date:  Time.zone.now.in_time_zone.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.in_time_zone.end_of_day)
                   .order(workout_date: :desc)
...
end
```

On my weights index view, all the records I enter for a day seem to stop showing after around 6:00pm US Eastern time.  They show fine during the day, but not in the evening.

I've tailed the log file in dev and on heroku (where my app lives), and the `Time.zone.now....end_of_day` is returning tomorrow's date.  i.e:

```
Fitness::Weight Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "fitness_weights".* FROM "fitness_weights" WHERE "fitness_weights"."admin_user_id" = $1 AND "fitness_weights"."workout_date" BETWEEN $2 AND $3 ORDER BY "fitness_weights"."workout_date" DESC  [["admin_user_id", 2], ["workout_date", "2021-11-21"], ["workout_date", "2021-11-21"]]
```

Today's date (this post) is "2021-11-20" not "2021-11-21".  I've checked both the dev and live databases for records entered today and they all show today's date, not "11-21".

In my application controller I set the time zone to US Eastern:

`config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`

but this is not helping.

How can I get this to show today's records at all times during the day?

I've also tried `Time.current.today` and `Time.today` and even `Date.today`.  All seem to want to return tomorrow's date when run in the evening hours here where I am.

Thanks for any tips.

`edited to add code for weights form and javascript`

```
views/fitness/weights/_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@weight) do |f| %>
...

<div class="grid-x">                                                                       
    <div class="cell medium-2">Date:</div>                                                   
    <div class="cell medium-2">
      <%= f.text_field :workout_date, { :size => 20, :type => 'date', :class => "date-picker", :readonly => false, :value => @weight.id ? @weight.workout_date : Date.today } %>
    </div>
  </div>

...

<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.date-picker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
</script>
```

`edited to show insert from log on heroku`

```
INSERT INTO "fitness_weights" ("workout_date", "muscle_group", "exercise", "weight_set_1", "reps_set_1", "weight_set_2", "reps_set_2", "weight_set_3", "reps_set_3", "weight_set_4", "reps_set_4", "weight_set_5", "pr", "comments", "admin_user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17) RETURNING "id"  [["workout_date", "2021-11-26"], ["muscle_group", "BICEPTS"], ["exercise", "SPIDER CURLS"], ["weight_set_1", "15"], ["reps_set_1", 15], ["weight_set_2", "15"], ["reps_set_2", 15], ["weight_set_3", "15"], ["reps_set_3", 15], ["weight_set_4", "20"], ["reps_set_4", 8], ["weight_set_5", ""], ["pr", ""], ["comments", ""], ["admin_user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2021-11-26 14:17:22.244589"], ["updated_at", "2021-11-26 14:17:22.244589"]]
```

Comment: How is `workout_date` being assigned when the Workout records are created?

Comment: obiruby - Thanks for looking at this.  I've edited my original post to add in the code for the weights form `workout_date` and the datepicker javascript.

Comment: @JohnCowan - can you please edit the question with params log when you submit the form? Curious to see the value of `workout_date` param.

Comment: @Nitin Srivastava - thanks for looking.  I edited my post to add in the insert lines from the log file on heroku.  Looks like the `workout_date` is coming through as `"2021-11-26"`

Comment: 8:36 pm New York time.  Today's date is Nov 26 2021.  Date.today on heroku console is Sat, 27 Nov 2021. In my local env Date.today shows "2021-11-26".  So there is that clue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a site that talked about using Time.zone.today instead of Date.today, which is another thing I tried.

```
@weights_today = Fitness::Weight.where(admin_user_id: session[:user_id])
                 .where(workout_date: Time.zone.today)
                 .order(workout_date: :desc)
```

This worked. The records on my `weights#index`view still show after 7:00pm.